# Is this a new function?

Tags: calculus, functions

Did I discover a new function:

$$ f(x)=\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{n}{a^{|nx|}} $$ where $ a>1 $?

The graph of this function looks like Dirac delta function.

Comment: What do you mean by a *new* function?

Comment: Dirac delta is not a function. There are deep reasons why you can treat it, in some circumstances, "as if" it were a function but it is worth being cautious in that usage. Normally, we call Dirac a "distribution." The above limit, since it doesn't exist at $x=0$, will have a different limit as a distribution.

Comment: I think your question is a bit vague: does this function show any particular property, apart from looking similar to the Dirac delta function? It converges to zero everywhere except in $x=0$, where is undefined: maybe it would be more interesting talking about the family of functions $n/a^{n|x|}$, rather than the limit.

Comment: As a distribution, I think your limit converges to $\frac{2}{\log a}\delta$ where $\delta$ is Dirac.

Comment: There are an infinite amount of functions to "discover."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take any even positive function $f$ with $$\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)dx=1$$
and, say, monotone on $(0,\infty)$
Then take $f_n(x):=nf(nx)$. This sequence is called an approximation of $\delta$-function. It's possible to show that in the sence of distributions indeed $f_n\to \delta_0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now take $f(x) =C a^{-|x|}$ (with $C>0$ chosen such that the integral condition holds) to obtain your example.